# sample spim code

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

I found this sample spim code on the internet

```
.data

COUNT:  .word   10
TEXT:   .asciiz "The number is "
EOL:    .asciiz "\n"

        .text
    .globl  main
main:

    addiu   $sp, $sp, -32   # Adjust stack
    sw  $ra, 24($sp)
    sw  $fp, 16($sp)    # save old frame pointer
    addiu   $fp, $sp, 28    # load new frame pointer    

    la  $t0, COUNT
    lw  $t1, 0($t0)
    li  $t0, 0      # init index to 0

loop:
    sw  $t0, 12($sp)    # save caller saved registers
    sw  $t1, 8($sp) # 

    move    $a0, $t0    # setup parameter for fn call

    jal print_num   # call subroutine

    lw  $t1, 8($sp) # restore caller saved values
    lw  $t0, 12($sp)    #

    addiu   $t0, $t0, 1 # increment index;
    blt $t0, $t1, loop  #

    lw  $fp, 16($sp)    # restore frame pointer
    lw  $ra, 24($sp)    # restore return address
    addiu   $sp, $sp, 32    # restore stack pointer

    jr  $ra
```

UPDATE
what I can't get is:
if function main needs to save four registers onto the stack ($ra $fp $t0 $t1),how come it allocates space for 8 registers (32 bytes instead of 16 bytes) ?

thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

The frame pointer should point to the beginning (bottom) of the stack. Since the stack elements are 4 bytes, the start of the bottom element is 4 less than the size of the stack.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the use of a convention, in particular a **calling convention**. In MIPS, the calleé saves some registers on the stack if it needs to use them, which registers need saving and where in the stack they are saved is specified in some convention. IDK about SPIM, but SGI IRIX had two different conventions called `o32` and `n32` (for "old" and "new"), you may have some luck googling for them.